# Is this a valid proof for proving the standard derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity, binomial-coefficients

A real analysis exam paper poses the question:

Prove that $x \to x^p$ has the derivative $px^{p-1}$where $p \in \mathbb R$

My attempt:

Let $f(x) = x^p$

Then the derivative at $c\in \mathbb R$ is the limit

$\lim_{x_\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ = $\lim_{x_\to c}\frac{x^p-c^p}{x-c}$

Using the binomial expansion(?):

this is equivalent to:

$\lim_{x_\to c}(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}c+...+c^{p-1})$

Where there are $p$ terms thus the limit becomes

$pc^{p-1}$

thus $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ the derivative is $px^{p-1}$

Any criticism is welcome and needed. Thankyou for reading.

Comment: This doesn't seem to cover any case except where $p$ is a nonnegative integer. In particular, it doesn't handle $p = \frac12$.

Comment: Ah knew I'd forgot something, so using the exponential definition of a power would suffice?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the exponential definition of a power," but presumably *you* do. Perhaps you can write out this proposed alternative proof for further evaluation.

Comment: $x^p = exp(plogx)$ is what I mean by the exponential definition, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PolynomialC Yes, the exponential definition is exactly how you should prove it.

Comment: Got it! Turns out its just chain rule!